# Import modules how to avoid double imports

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm relatively new to python. I try to tidy up a working program by putting the functions in a separate module, Now I have the following function

```
def funcswitch(x):
    if (pd.isnull(x.iloc[23])) | (x.iloc[23] == '--'):        
        return x.iloc[22]
    return x.iloc[23]
```

Where pd is a pandas dataframe.

I call the function like this:

```
dfIn['cat'] = dfIn.apply(funcswitch, axis=1)
```

If I put the function in a separate module. pd is highlighted as unknown. When I do an import;  `import pandas as pd` in the module also, and do the following in the main code

```
import myfunctions as m
.....
dfIn['cat'] = dfIn.apply(m.funcswitch, axis=1)
```

...everything works okay but this looks a bit silly to me.
I just want the import:  `import pandas as pd` in the main module. So how can I avoid the double import?